# Is matching with id performant in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j

I'm wondering, when I have read the data of a node and I want to match it in another query, which way will have the best performance? Using `id` like this:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = 1234
```

or using indices of the node:

```
MATCH (n:Label {SomeIndexProperty: 3456})
```

Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDs` are a technical ID for Neo4j, and those should not be used as a primary key for your application.

Every node (and relationship) has a technical ID, and it's stable over time.
But if you delete a node, for example the node `32`, Neo4j will reuse this `ID` for a new node.

So you can use it in your queries inside the same transaction (there is no problem), otherwise you should know what you are doing.

The **only** way to retrieve the technical `ID`, is to use the function `ID` like you do on your first query : `MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = 1234 RETURN n`.
The `ID` is not exposed as a node's property, so you **can't** do `MATCH (n {ID:1234}) RETURN n`.

You have noticed that if you want to do a `WHERE` on a strict equality, you can do put the condition directly on the node.
For example :

- `MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.name = 'logisima' RETURN n`
- `MATCH (n:Node {name:'logisima'}) RETURN n`

Those two queries are identicals, they generate the same query plan, it's just a syntactic sugar.

### Is it faster to retrieve a node by its ID or by an indexed property ?

The easier way to know the answer to this question is to profile the two queries.

On the one based on the `ID`, you will see the box `NodeByIdSeek` that cost *1 db hit*, and on the one with a unique constrainst you will see the box `NodeUniqueIndexSeek` with *2 db hits*.

So searching a node by its `ID` is faster.

Comment: Yeah, I know the only way is using `id()` function. I meant using some property called `ID` in the second query.

Comment: My question was mainly about the performance of two approaches, using id or property for matching.

Comment: @Ahmad Your second query will perform badly. Looking up a node without a label and just a property will perform an AllNodesScan, the worst performing lookup. If you had a label on the node in your MATCH then it would perform a NodeByLabelScan, which would be better. If you used a label and had an index using the label/property combination then it would be a NodeIndexSeek which would be the next best performance after the direct id() lookup.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thanks. I've updated my question to make it more precise.